# How can parse text in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have `<RequestorID Instance="2005-03-02T10:47:39"></RequestorID>`

Need give 2005 and 03 and 02 in 3 variable.
How do it?

I use `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">`

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:variable name="month" select="substring(RequestorID/@Instance, 6, 2)" />
```